# Effect mapping and agile development

Tags: agile

Today, I have found a new technique for Agile Development named "Effect Mapping", developed by Gojko Adzic:

http://gojko.net/effect-map/

The main idea behind it is about building the map tree of a project, before starting with the first agile story. It helps creating the eye bird view of the entire project, so you can start stories with a minimum viable plan.

1. How would you mix effect mapping with agile stories?
2. for people not using effect mapping, that i think is 99% of people, how do you approach the eye bird project view before starting with the first iteration? I feel really fustrating when you are dealing with a forest of stories before starting the first iteration.

Comment: fyi, it's "bird's eye view" not "eye bird view"

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing this technique , it is really interesting & worth a try.

I didn't personally try it *yet* but by reading the paper & watching the video I kind of an found an answer to your first question :

> How would you mix effect mapping with agile stories?

By referring to *Iterative product release planning* and *Focusing deliverables on business value increments* sections will help you mix both user stories with effect mapping techniques.

Regarding the second question

> how do you approach the eye bird project view before starting with the first iteration?

I find this technique [It's All in How you slice](http://www.agileproductdesign.com/writing/how_you_slice_it.pdf) is really useful and effective to get an overview of your product.

Thanks...

Comment: ,thanks for your answer.I also found your last technique on internet. It looks good, but still trying to mix between agile terminology (user stories and tasks), with this "new" workflow technique (activity, task, tool), that i think its absolutely a must if you want to create a basic big picture and dont get lost in the forest